# Powerpoint VBA Change All Text Color within Chart

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I have a macro that pastes charts from excel into powerpoint, but depending on the slide it goes onto, the font color sometimes changes (despite pasting with source formatting - can't use metafile etc. as need it to be easy to edit).

So after it gets pasted I want to change the color of all the text to black.

I have managed this with certain parts of the chart - e.g. Title & Legend, but am struggling with the other areas - or ideally a way to change it all at once.

What I have that is working is:

```
    activeShape.Chart.ChartTitle.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
    activeShape.Chart.Legend.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
```

But then trying to do the whole chart with something like this doesn't work (I get 'The Specified Value is Out of Range'):

```
    activeShape.Chart.ChartArea.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
```

Could anyone help me with how I change all the text color in the chart at once?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
activeShape.Chart.ChartArea.Font.Color = vbBlack
```